# I listen to music when I work out. I listen to music when I cook. - I want to combine them, and should I use "or" or "and"?

Tags: meaning

I listen to music when I work out.
I listen to music when I cook.

I want to combine them, and should I use "or" or "and"?

**Example 1**
When I work out or I cook, I listen to music.

**Example 2**
When I work out and I cook, I listen to music.

**Example 3**
When I work out or when I cook, I listen to music.

**Example 4**
When I work out and when I cook, I listen to music.

Comment: Imho it's relevant that *in general*, there's no particular connection between "working out" and "cooking" in the context of listening to music. Likely interpretations (and their relationship to grammar/syntax) would be very different with, say, *When I **have my phone** AND/OR **my smart speaker** with me, I listen to music*. Thus I think this question is more about ***likely real-world meanings*** than about the English language as such.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Sorry I don't understand the "particular connection between working out and cooking." Would you explain it more? And what do you think about my examples? Do Examples 3 and 4 mean the same? Does Example 4 mean that "when I work out and cook at the same time, I listen to music"?

Comment: I said there is ***no*** connection between  "working out" and "cooking" (the word "particular" is just a kind of "optional intensifier" in that context). So we'd have no reason to think it's likely that *both apply at once* in your example, but that's quite possible with ***my*** example. Perhaps I bluetooth the music from my smartphone to my battery-powered wireless speaker, so I actually ***need*** both, OR perhaps *either* device can produce the music *on its own.*

Comment: ...the actual syntactic construction is *ambiguous* with ***and*** (but not with ***or***). But logic and the specific context may encourage you to interpret ***and*** as equivalent to ***or***, OR circumstances may make it obvious that the ***or*** interpretation is unlikely, so the intended sense would be that ***both*** conditions must be true.

Comment: See (possible duplicate?) ["inclusive or" can mean one element, any two elements, or more in a list?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/256716/inclusive-or-can-mean-one-element-any-two-elements-or-more-in-a-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examples 3 and 4 are both correct and in practice mean the same thing. Examples 1 and 2 are awkward, and sound more natural as "When I work out and/or cook, I listen to music". In this case the sentence using "or" has the same meaning as examples 3 and 4. However, saying "When I work out and cook, I listen to music" only says that you listen to music when you are working out and cooking at the same time.

Comment: Thank you. So Examples 3 and 4 both mean “I listen to music when I work out, and I listen to music when I cook”? Is there a possibility that Example 4 gets interpreted as "I listen to music when I do work out and cook at the same time"?

Comment: No, it would not be interpreted that way. It is the most natural way to say what you want. Using "or" (like example 3) is less natural, so if somebody wonders why you used "or" they might think you are saying that you listen when you cook, or when you work out, but not when you do both together. Most people would not think about it, and would take the sentences to mean the same thing.

Comment: Thank you. Just to make sure I understand correctly. Example 3 means "when I work out, I listen to music, and when I cook, I listen to music. But I probably don't listen to music when I do both," right? Example 4 means "when I work out, I listen to music, and when I cook, I listen to music. And I probably listen to music when I do both," right?

Comment: Example 4 means I listen to music: A when I am working out and not cooking, B when I am cooking and not working out, and C when I am doing both at the same time. Example 3 would usually be understood to mean the same thing, but somebody might think that I listen to music for A and B, but not C. Example 4 is the best sentence of the four to use.